# error compiling node

Tags: ros, build-package, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and ros kinetic

I created a package for a subscriber node(start_goal_generator.cpp), this node must get the published topic "map" from map_server node

i tried to build the workspace with catkin_make, the output  is:

```
Base path: /home/evadro/Desktop/Eman/ros_workspace
Source space: /home/evadro/Desktop/Eman/ros_workspace/src
Build space: /home/evadro/Desktop/Eman/ros_workspace/build
Devel space: /home/evadro/Desktop/Eman/ros_workspace/devel
Install space: /home/evadro/Desktop/Eman/ros_workspace/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/evadro/Desktop/Eman/ros_workspace/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/evadro/Desktop/Eman/ros_workspace/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/evadro/Desktop/Eman/ros_workspace/devel;/home/evadro/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/evadro/Desktop/Eman/ros_workspace/devel;/home/evadro/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.12", minimum required is "2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python2
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/evadro/Desktop/Eman/ros_workspace/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found version "2.7.12") 
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.29
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 6 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - rosbot_ekf
-- ~~  - start_goal_generator
-- ~~  - rplidar_ros
-- ~~  - rosbot_navigation
-- ~~  - rosbot_description
-- ~~  - rosbot_gazebo
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosbot_ekf'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(rosbot_ekf)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- rosbot_ekf: 1 messages, 1 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'start_goal_generator'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(start_goal_generator)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rplidar_ros'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(rplidar_ros)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosbot_navigation'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(rosbot_description/src/rosbot_navigation)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosbot_description'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(rosbot_description/src/rosbot_description)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rosbot_gazebo'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(rosbot_description/src/rosbot_gazebo)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/evadro/Desktop/Eman/ros_workspace/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j24 -l24" in "/home/evadro/Desktop/Eman/ros_workspace/build"
####
[  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target _catkin_empty_exported_target
[  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target _rosbot_ekf_generate_messages_check_deps_Imu
[  6%] Built target start_goal_generator_node
[  6%] Built target _rosbot_ekf_generate_messages_check_deps_Configuration
[ 13%] Built target rplidarNodeClient
[ 36%] Built target rplidarNode
[ 63%] Built target rosbot_ekf_generate_messages_py
[ 60%] Built target rosbot_ekf_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 63%] Built target rosbot_ekf_generate_messages_lisp
[ 80%] Built target rosbot_ekf_generate_messages_cpp
[ 80%] Built target rosbot_ekf_generate_messages_eus
[ 80%] Built target rosbot_ekf_generate_messages
[ 86%] Built target msgs_conversion
[ 93%] Built target move_base_ws2812b_example
[100%] Built target cmd_vel_ws2812b_example
```

**when I try to compile the node: g++ start_goal_generator.cpp**

**it gives error:**

start_goal_generator.cpp:1:10: fatal error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory
#include "ros/ros.h"

compilation terminated.

**This is start_goal_generator.cpp**

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid.h"
#include "std_msgs/Header.h"
#include "nav_msgs/MapMetaData.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <random>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;
std::default_random_engine generator; 
unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);

//#include "quadtree.h"

ros::Publisher map_pub;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
double calculateDistance(int sRow, int sColumn, int gRow, int gColumn)
{
  double dist;
  dist= sqrt((pow((sRow - gRow),2))+pow((sColumn - gColumn),2));
  return dist;
}// end function calculateDistance
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void mapCallback(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  std_msgs::Header header = msg->header;
  nav_msgs::MapMetaData info = msg->info;
  ROS_INFO("Got map %d %d", info.width, info.height);
  


  int width = info.width;
    int height = info.height;
    int startCell=0;
    int goalCell=0;
  long cellID=-1;
    int startRow = 0;
    int startColumn = 0;
    int goalRow = 0;
    int goalColumn = 0;
    int max_value = height * width;
  int numberOfScenarios = 30;

  srand ( time(NULL) );
    sleep(1.0);

  for(int scenario=1; scenario <= numberOfScenarios; scenario++)
  {
      // choose random start
      do{ 
        cellID = (rand() % max_value);
        startCell = cellID;
      }while(msg->data[startCell] != 0);

      startRow = cellID/width;
      startColumn = cellID%width;
      
      // choose random goal
      double thresholdDistance= 8.0;  // 8.0 meter

      do{ 
        cellID = (rand() % max_value);
        goalCell = cellID;
        goalRow= cellID/width;
        goalColumn=cellID%width;
      }while ((goalCell == startCell) || (msg->data[goalCell] != 0) || (calculateDistance(startRow,startColumn,goalRow,goalColumn) < thresholdDistance)); 
      
      // write start and goal to text file
      // create text file
      ofstream scenarios_textfile ("rosMapRandomScenarios.txt", ios::app);
      // write startCell and goalCell 
      scenarios_textfile <<startCell<<" "<< goalCell<<endl;
  }// end for each scenario

}// end function mapCallback

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "grid");
  ros::NodeHandle n;

  //map_pub = n.advertise<nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid>("map_out",10);
  ros::Subscriber map_sub = n.subscribe("map",10,mapCallback);
  
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}// end main
```

**This is package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>start_goal_generator</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The start_goal_generator package generates a set of start and goal scenarios</description>

  <maintainer email="evadro@todo.todo">evadro</maintainer>

  <license>TODO</license>
  
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>nav_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_export_depend>roscpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>rospy</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>nav_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>rospy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>nav_msgs</exec_depend>


  <!-- The export tag contains other, unspecified, tags -->
  <export>
    <!-- Other tools can request additional information be placed here -->
  </export>
</package>
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(start_goal_generator)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
## add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  nav_msgs
)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES start_goal_generator
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs nav_msgs
)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(start_goal_generator_node
  src/start_goal_generator.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(start_goal_generator_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Thanks,,,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/376777/error-compiling-node/) by [Eman.m](https://answers.ros.org/users/42689/eman.m/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2021-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**This is CMakeLists.txt that works**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(start_goal_generator)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
## add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  nav_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES start_goal_generator
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs nav_msgs
)

include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(start_goal_generator_node
  src/start_goal_generator_node.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(start_goal_generator_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

** ros c++ nodes are not compiled with g++, now my node works perfectly. NOTE: I changed the node file name to start_goal_generator_node.cpp**

---

Originally posted by [Eman.m](https://answers.ros.org/users/42689/eman.m/) with karma: 65 on 2021-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0